# What disk is being filled on my Azure Worker Role?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights, azure-worker-roles

I have a WorkerRole on Azure that has been working fine for years and suddenly stopped working today.  If I look at the Azure Infrastructure Logs I see lots of errors saying:

> EventName=""InfrastructureLogsEvent"" Message=""System.IO.IOException:
>   There is not enough space on the disk.
>
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
>   maybeFullPath)    at System.IO.FileStream.WriteCore(Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 count)    at
>   System.IO.FileStream.FlushWrite(Boolean calledFromFinalizer)    at
>   System.IO.FileStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)    at
>   System.IO.Stream.Close()    at System.IO.StreamWriter.Dispose(Boolean
>   disposing)    at System.IO.TextWriter.Dispose()    at
>   System.IO.File.InternalWriteAllText(String path, String contents,
>   Encoding encoding, Boolean checkHost)    at
>   ApplicationInsightsExtension.LogPublisherBase.set_LastQueryCutOffTimeStamp(DateTime
>   value)"" ManagerTid=""4"" OrigTS=""2018/05/08 03:20:41.211""
>   TraceSource=""Diagnostics""

With a few that say:

> "The total available space in disk directory partition
>   C:\Resources\directory\06767544226d408d94d0d752584ca35d.InSysMinuteDataProcessor.DiagnosticStore\WAD0107\Tables\
>   is 0MB; adjusting down quota from 2560MB to 2048MB so more table data
>   is garbage collected. Make sure MA's directory partition and quota are
>   large enough and other processes are not writing data into and filling
>   the partition."

These are the only errors and they started being generated today for the first time.  The CPU for the WorkerRole is now running at close to 100% and not doing any of the processing it is designed to do.

I have tried turning off Application Insights and redploying the WorkerRole, which had no effect.  I also deleted the Cloud Service instance and all its deployments and recreated it with a different name.  Again I see the same errors.

When I run the WorkerRole in debug mode in Visual Studio it is working fine.  Why has it suddenly stopped working when deployed in Azure?

Comment: Don't use the `C:` drive in WorkerRoles, it's a small disk intended only for operating-system files. Use the `D:` drive instead which is intended for temporary files: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2013/12/06/understanding-the-temporary-drive-on-windows-azure-virtual-machines/

Comment: I'm not using the disk for anything intentionally.  The worker role just pulls messages from a Queue, does a bit of processing, and saves to Table Storage - at no point do I explicitly save to the disk. The issues seems to be related to Application Insights.

Comment: I should add that when I RDP into the instance to check the space available on the various drives, they all have *lots* of space.  The C: drive has 214GB available.

Comment: I have made some progress.  I still don't know what the cause is, but 'reimaging' the instance (via the Azure Portal), seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: I also removed all the Nuget packages associated with Application Insights.  At the moment, I'm thinking that the way AI collects data from a Worker Role has changed significantly since I first added AI to this WR.